# Magento 2 : Order Edit Error "No such entity with cartId = 458"

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, multistore, entities

When I am going to edit order then getting an error like above.

> No such entity with cartId = 458.

[image: Magento 2 No such entity with cartId]

I have 4 stores in my project.

[image]

Order edit works fine for 1 store but for another store it gives error
and in DB for 1 store it inserts 2 rows, for another 4 rows.

I am not getting anything.
Working on multi-site setup.

Comment: If anybody have questions about this  issue plz ask.

Comment: i have a question nitesh...how i solve this issue please give me a solution.....

Comment: @Doss In my case, there was one extension we were using and because of that extension we were facing this issue, then after disable that extension, issue was fixed. After that, we found out that conflict (unable to remember all things) and finally solved this issue.

Comment: @Doss Can you tell more about your issue?

Comment: When I Give invoice for my order in admin side...Sales->Settings->orders->Invoice..No such entity with cartId = 458 error message is shown..What is the problem for that.please give me a solution @nitesh

Comment: @Doss You need to check log files first and then you can solve your issue. Right now, I am unable to give you correct solution cause your case is different. Also, under github issues you will know how to debug this issue.

Comment: @Doss plz check quote table first as told in answer.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the current store has always the default store ID in the admin panel (on the fronted everything is OK).

As result I catch the No such entity with cartId = xxx ... exception, because Magento tries to retrieve quote with this ID from the default store, which does not exist.

```
$store_old = $this->_storeManager->getStore();

$store = $this->_storeManager->getStore(Pass YOUR STORE ID);

$this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore($store); // Add this to avoid cart issue
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check your theme directories for any mis-use of `Magento_Customer/js/customer-data` I have found on multiple occasions when debugging that many devs opt to manipulate customer data to achieve things. Here was one I found recently in the `placeOrder: function () {` method of a third-party payment gateway integration that had been internally manipulated within the theme:

```js
var clearData = {
  'selectedShippingAddress': null,
  'shippingAddressFromData': null,
  'newCustomerShippingAddress': null,
  'selectedShippingRate': null,
  'selectedPaymentMethod': null,
  'selectedBillingAddress': null,
  'billingAddressFromData': null,
  'newCustomerBillingAddress': null
};
customerData.set('checkout-data', clearData);
```

So search `app/design/frontend` for `Magento_Customer/js/customer-data` and see what naughties pop-up!